# Finding the probability of winning lottery in four different conditions

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, lotteries

There is a lottery game , it consists of $6$ block and each blocks contains numbers from $1$ to $90$.When you play the lottery , you should select one number from each of these $6$ blocks.

$\color{red}{a-)}$ What is the probability of winning lottery if winner numbers are different from each other (i.e repetition is not allowed) and the order of numbers matters?

(for example if winner lottery is $5-12-45-85-3-2$ respectively, you cannot take money if your numbers are $12-5-45-85-3-2$ ,respectively.)

$\color{red}{b-)}$ What is the probability of winning lottery if winner numbers can repeat and the order of numbers are matter ?

$\color{red}{c-)}$ What is the probability of winning lottery if winner numbers are different from each other (i.e repetition is not allowed) and the order of numbers does not matter ?

(For example , if the seleced numbers are $3-4-56-78-46-33$ , then the tickets have any permutation of these numbers will be winner such that $3-4-56-78-46-33$ ,$56-78-46-3-4-33$ ,$4-78-33-46-56-3$ ,etc  are winners)

$\color{red}{d-)}$ What is the probability of winning lottery if winner numbers can repeat and the order of numbers does not matter ?

(For example , if the winner numbers are $2-19-2-89-89-23$, then any permutation of them can take prize such as $2-19-2-89-89-23$ ,or $19-2-2-23-89-89$ ,or  $89-2-23-89-2-19$ )

MY ATTEMPT:

$\color{blue}{a-)}$ $\frac{1}{P(90,6)}$

$\color{blue}{b-)}$ $\frac{1}{90^{6}}$

$\color{blue}{c-)}$ $6! \times \frac{1}{P(90,6)}$

$\color{blue}{d-)}$ I thought that i should make use of exponential function such as $(e^x)^6 $ and find the coefficient of $\frac{x^6}{6!}$ , so the answer is $\frac{6^6}{90^6} $ or should i use $(e^x)^{90} $ and find the coefficient of $\frac{x^6}{6!}$ , so the answer is $\frac{90^6}{90^6}=1 $

Is my solutions correct ? If not , can you help to correct them ?

EDITED NOTE = selection probability of each number is equal

Comment: Your answers to (a), (b) and (c) look correct.  The answer to $d$ may depend on how the winning numbers are selected both by you and the lottery; I suspect $1-2-3-4-5-6$ may be more likely than $1-1-1-1-1-1$ so the probability may depend on which choice you make

Comment: @Henry selection probablity of each numbers are equal

Comment: So if there were two numbers and two selections, what would be the probability of $1-2$ being drawn? In (a) it is $\frac12$.  In (b) it is $\frac14$.  In (c) it is $1$.  In (d) what is it? $\frac12$ or $\frac13$? I think it is $\frac12$ and twice as likely as $1-1$ or $2-2$

Comment: @Henry your point is fine for part $a,b,c$ but not $d$. As far as i have understood , OP want to find all possible probability when it is said repetition allowed and order does not matter. So , you should take $1-1 , 2-2$ into account , then it gave us $4/4=1$. I think that second solution of part d is correct

Comment: @Bulbasaur on (d) I know in my toy example  the three possibilities are $1-2,1-1,2-2$ so their probabilities add up to $1$.  My point is that I think it should be (i) $\frac12 + \frac14 + \frac14=1$ but it could be (ii) $\frac13+\frac13+\frac13$.  Either way, in the original question both $\frac{6^6}{90^6}$ and $\frac{90^6}{90^6}$ are too high.

Comment: If (i) is correct then the probability is at most $\frac{6!}{90^6} \approx 1.35\times 10^{-9}$ if all your choices are distinct and at least $\frac{1}{90^6}\approx 1.88 \times 10^{-12}$ if all your choices are the same.  If you are selecting at random then I think the answer is a complicated $\frac{390989186423}{313810596090000000000} \approx 1.246 \times \times 10^{-9}$

Comment: If (ii) is correct then it is again complicated but I think it becomes $\frac1{869107785}\approx 1.15 \times \times 10^{-9} $